# Smart Table search not working when creating multiple tables

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

This is what I am doing.
I call a rest api which returns response in this format

"metalanguages": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Abkhaz"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Afar"
        }
      },
    "manufacturers": {
        "-1": {
            "id": -1,
            "name": "all"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "RIM"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "HP"
        }
    }

This is basically a Map of String and Map.
I now have to create n number of table where n is number of keys of original map and inside each table I have to show data which will be the value of internal map ("id": 2,
            "name": "HP")

I have made it working but search is not working.
This is my sample code

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in metadataDetails">
<table  st-table="metadataCollection" st-safe-src="metadataDetails" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
   <tr class="style_tr">
   <th st-sort="name">name</th>
   <th st-sort="name">name</th>
   <th st-sort="description">description</th>
   <th st-sort="countryName">countryName</th>
   <th st-sort="carrierName">carrierName</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="textSearchTr">
   <th colspan="4" class="textSearchTr">
   <input class="freshblue" placeholder="Enter value to search/filter" type="text" ng-model="searchParam.search" />
   </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in getValueMap(key)" ng-show="showRow">
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And my js file

```
AuditMetadataService.get({}, function(data) {

        $scope.numRecord = data.length;
        $scope.metadataDetails = data;
        $scope.metadataCollection = [].concat($scope.metadataDetails);
        console.log("Return value :");
        console.log($scope.metadataDetails);
    });

$scope.getValueMap = function(key) {

        console.log(key);
        return $scope.metadataDetails[key];

    };
```

Could someone please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your map object into an array by getting it's keys and using the `Array.prototype.map` function, you will have to repeat this for the inner map objects as well because `st-sort` expects an array item, not a key value.

```
$scope.tables = keys.map(function(key) {
    return Object.keys(data[key]).map(function(k) {
        return data[key][k];
    });
});
```

Then you can iterate `$scope.tables` using `ng-repeat` to create all the tables want, clicking the column titles will now sort them properly.

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bi6JfN?p=preview).